# Writing a half-ray as a countable union

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I was trying to prove that monotone increasing functions are Borel measurable and I came across a step where I had to write $[x_0, \infty)$ as a countable union, I suggested either $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [x_0,n)$ or $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [x_0, n]$. I am unsure which one to choose however, are both right?

Comment: Both of them are right, you can check it by double-inclusion and by going back to what it means to be in an union.

Comment: A countable union of what?